# localhost different css than production build

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

here is the production build https://daotec.herokuapp.com/

this is what i see in my localhost
[image]
on hover the button is blue on the production build on hover it turns green and also has a white border where in localhost it has a white border and
[image]
the icons are centered where you can see in production build they are not. Does anyone know why this is happening? Also could anyone tell me how to get my container of hectagons to be in the very center of the screen? here is my code

CSS

```css
.icon {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.hexs {
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 30px;
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.hex1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  width: 230px;
}

#fastest {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.para {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.hexa {
  width: 104px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.tri1 {
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: 30px solid blueviolet;
  border-left: 52px solid transparent;
  border-right: 52px solid transparent;
}

.tri2 {
  width: 0;
  border-top: 30px solid blueviolet;
  border-left: 52px solid transparent;
  border-right: 52px solid transparent;
}

.container {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.75rem black);
}
```

HTML

```html
<div className="head">
  <h1>About</h1>
</div>
<hr />
<div className="hexs">
  <div className="hex">
    <div className="hex1">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="tri1"></div>
        <div className="hexa">
          <i className="fas fa-tachometer-alt icon fa-3x"></i>
        </div>
        <div className="tri2"></div>
      </div>
      <div className="fast">
        <h3 id="fastest">Fast</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p className="para">
          Fast load times and lag free interaction, my highest priority.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="hex1">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="tri1"></div>
        <div className="hexa">
          <i className="fas fa-laptop-code icon fa-3x"></i>
        </div>
        <div className="tri2"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Responsive</h3>
        <p>My layouts will work on any device, big or small.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="hex">
    <div className="hex1">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="tri1"></div>
        <div className="hexa">
          <i className="far fa-lightbulb icon fa-3x"></i>
        </div>
        <div className="tri2"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Intuitive</h3>
        <p>Strong preference for easy to use, intuitive UX/UI.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="hex1">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="tri1"></div>
        <div className="hexa">
          <i className="fas fa-rocket icon fa-3x"></i>
        </div>
        <div className="tri2"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Dynamic</h3>
        <p>
          Websites don't have to be static, I love making pages come to
          life.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tripple check if your codes are the same.

Comment: what do you mean check if my codes are the same? the css file with min.css in the build folder

Comment: Check if production and localhost codes are the same. Maybe you forgot a build step, a cleanup-step before build, a refresh or something.

Comment: im not using react native im using react. and im building with react-scripts-build then deploying the build i get to react-scripts-build. However, when i serve the build before deployment its showing the same problem!

Comment: Try to reload the page cache. `CRTL + F5` on Windows or `Command + Shift + R` on Mac.